Better proof that the induced map on deRham cohomology is injective for $k \ge 0$
This question is from a publicly available practice qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I have seen no proof for this problem in any textbook; all work is my own, so I want to make sure my own unique solution looks good. I had a hard time using Lee's book to find a solution, until Lee himself recommended I extend the proof of one of his lemmas. I took his advice and rewrote the proof, using his work for reference. I'm unsure whether the way in which I extended his work is correct, particularly regarding deck transformations instead of orientation coverings, and I'm unsure how his definition of the global form $\beta$ (and by extension my definition) helps show global injectivity from local bijectivity.

Question: Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a smooth, finite covering map between smooth n-dimensional manifolds. Show that the induced map on deRham cohomology
$$ f^* : H^k_{dR}(Y ; \mathbb R) \rightarrow H _{dR}^k (X ; \mathbb R)$$
is injective, for all $k \ge 0$.

Answer: We'll use a similar strategy that Lee used in his lemma (page 456)

Lemma 17.33 Suppose M is a connected nonorientable smooth manifold and $\hat \pi : \hat M \rightarrow M$ is its orientation covering. For each $k$, the induced cohomology maps $\hat \pi^* : H_\text{dR}^k \rightarrow H_\text{dR}^k$ and $\hat \pi ^* : H_c^k (M) \rightarrow H_c^k (\hat M)$

For Lee's case, the covering space is 2-sheeted, and we have two deck transformations (identity and nontrivial automorphism). For the broader class of cases that we're dealing with, we can keep the structure of his proof similar, but have to address more deck transformations.
We'll also employ Lee's Following Theorem (page 447)

Theorem 17.14 (The Poincare Lemma) If $U$ is a star-shaped open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb H^n$, then $H_\text{dR}^k(U) = 0$ for $k \ge 1$.

Furthermore, in conjunction with diffeomorphism invariance, this means means that any neighborhood diffeomorphic to $U$ shares this property.

Assume a normal covering. We know that the pullback of all closed forms remains a closed form:
$$ d \omega = 0 \implies f^* d \omega = f^* (0) = 0 $$
Since all of our forms are pulled back onto a neighborhood diffeomorphic to a star-shaped subset, we have that all of our pulled back closed forms are exact in $Y$. Since there may be closed forms in $Y$ that are not exact, we know that locally at least the pullback is injective. We need to construct from this a global form that satisfies this property.
Suppose $\omega$ is a closed $k$-form on $Y$ such that $f^* [\omega] = 0 \in H_\text{dR}^k (X)$. Then there exists $\alpha \in \Omega^k (X)$ such that $d \alpha = f* \omega$
Have $n$ be the degree of our covering. For $q \in 1, 2, \dots , n $, have $\{A_q \}_q$ be the collection of deck transformations of $X$. The composition of any deck transformation with $f$ will still be $f$, which has a corresponding implication for pullbacks;
$$ f (A_q) = f \implies A_q^* f^* = f^* \omega$$
We can construct a form $\widetilde \alpha$ that is invariant under any deck transformation:
$$ \widetilde \alpha_q = (1/n) \sum_q A_q^* \alpha$$
We know this is invariant, because each each composition $A_j \circ A_i$ is a unique $A_k$. That is, any $$A_i \circ \widetilde \alpha = (1/n) \sum_q  (A_q \circ A_i)^* \alpha = \sum_k A_k^* \alpha $$ simply permutes the order of elements in the sum. Since this is a sum, we can simply rearrange the sum back into being $A_i  \widetilde \alpha = \widetilde \alpha$. It is also true that $d \widetilde \alpha = f^* \omega $
There are a total of $n$ local sections over every $U$. Each section  is related by some deck transformation; $\sigma_j = A_j \sigma_i$. Observe that $$ \sigma_j^* \widetilde \alpha = (A_j \circ \sigma_i)^* \widetilde \alpha = \sigma_i^*  A_j^* \widetilde \alpha = \sigma_i^* \widetilde \alpha  $$
Therefore, we define a smooth global $(k - 1)$ form $\beta$ on $Y$ be setting $\beta|_U = \sigma^* \widetilde \alpha $  for any smooth local section $\sigma: Y \rightarrow X$; the argument above guarantees that the various definitions agree where the overlap. To determine the exterior derivative of $\beta$, given $p \in M$, choose a smooth local section $\sigma$ defined on a neighborhood $U$ of $p$, and compute
$$ d \beta = d \sigma^* \widetilde \alpha = \sigma^* d \widetilde \alpha = \sigma^* f* \omega = (f \circ \sigma)^* \omega = \omega $$ because $f \circ \sigma = \text{Id}_U$.

I have two subquestions, in order of importance:
(a) Is my use of deck coverings, automorphisms, and the construction of $\widetilde \alpha$ correct?
(b) How does the extension of the idea of $\widetilde \alpha$ to a global form $\beta$, which agrees on any intersecting sections $\sigma$, imply that the global map of the de Rham cohomology is injective? Is the implication that $d \beta = \omega$ on $Y$  highly important aspect of Lee's proof (and by extension mine)?
Thanks in advance.
